# Extract Data from multiple files and POPULATE the masterfile

Tags: extract

I'm Akshey and I am new to VBA. I have just started learning the basics. Would really appreciate if you could help me with this situation.

In our organisation we have to fill an " `Availability Tracker` " specifying the hours we are free to work ( incase of no schedule work ) and incase we have work our senior/ supervisor, the work and the hours.

Till now we had a single shared sheet for 120 employees. What I am thinking of doing is that there should be 120 sheets ( one for each employee ). These files will be saved to one folder. There will be macro enabled Master File which will extract all the data

Here is the example of individual Sheet ( the way I want it to be ) :

```
   A              B      C       D      E      F     G
1
2 Snr.>/ Staff|         Snr. 1        Snr. 2        Snr. 2
3                    Client Hrs      Client Hrs    Client Hrs
4 Staff 1             XYZ    2         LMP   3       -     -
```

Every employee will fill B4:G4 everyday.

Here is the example of the master file :

Note : All the files will be having the same format. The master file will have the same format. And data has to pulled from the individual sheets and populated to Masterfile

```
   A              B      C       D      E      F     G
1
2 Snr.>/ Staff|         Snr. 1        Snr. 2        Snr. 2
3                    Client Hrs      Client Hrs    Client Hrs
4 Staff 1             XYZ    2         LMP   3       -     -
4 Staff 2             ABC    1         LMP   3       -     -
4 Staff 3             APP    5         LMP   3       -     -
4 Staff 4 .. 12       XYZ    2         LMP   3       -     -
```

.....

Basically what I want is that masterfile to be updated with data in `B4:G4` of every individual sheets.

Any help would be appreciated !